LET Function and IFS Function
Column C is titled Initial Inspection Date and the date is in the format, (2024-09-26) or (yyyy-mm-dd) as a text. Column D is titled Labwork Status with the option of having "New". If the Initial Inspection Date is not less then 30 days, in Column K titled Notes, it should return "New". If it is 30 day and less than 60 days, it should return Move to In-Process for Column K, titled Notes. If it is 60 days or more, it should return "Past Due Move to In-Process". Let say I have date: (2024-10-02) in Column C2 and Column D2 is "New", I want to get back "New" in Column K, Notes, but it is returning "TRUE" in K2. What is wrong with my equation below?
=LET(C_, DATEVALUE(C2),IFS(D2="New",C_>NOW()-30,"New","Move to In-Process",D2="New",C_>NOW()-60,"New","Past Due Move to In-Process"))

The above is the equation and I want to understand how it is working and how to improve that equation so that I get the results that I am looking for.
How does the function work for LET, =LET(Name, Name_Value, Calcuation), and for IFS =IFS([Something is True1, Value if True1,Something is True2,Value if True2,Something is True3,Value if True3)? It looks like it is my structure of the IFS statement.  Can any one confirm that and help me understand what I need to change with my IFS statement to get it to work correctly?
To Return "New" in the Column K titled Notes and instead, I am getting "TRUE" if the date is (2024-09-26) and "FALSE" if the date is (2024-08-26) This is United States date format being Year, month and day. (yyyy-mm-dd)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try =LET(iid,NOW()-DATEVALUE(C2),IF(D2="New",IFS(iid<30,"New",iid<60,"Move to In-Process",TRUE,"Past Due Move to In-Process"),"")).

@VBasic2008, I learnt about NOW() now ;) BTW, I used lengthy conditions in my answer just to spell it out.


but it is returning "TRUE" in K2

In
=LET(
    C_, DATE(LEFT(C2, 4), MID(C2, 6, 2), RIGHT(C2, 2)),
    IFS(
        D2 = "New",
        C_ > NOW() - 30,
        "New",
        "Move to In-Process",
        D2 = "New",
        C_ > NOW() - 60,
        "New",
        "Past Due Move to In-Process"
    )
)

the first condition is D2 = "New" which is TRUE and the value to return is C_ > NOW() - 30, which is also TRUE. I think you meant to have AND both conditions.

Here's an alternative:
=LET(
    inspection_dates, C2:C6, lab_status, D2:D6,
    days_since, NOW() - DATEVALUE(inspection_dates),
    IFS(
        lab_status <> "New", "",
        days_since < 30, "New",
        days_since < 60, "Move to In-Process",
        days_since >= 60, "Past Due Move to In-Process"))


Thanks to VBasic2008's comment, I'm using NOW() instead of TODAY() (though it would work as well)

Thank you for your help. This equation works, but I would like to understand why?  =LET(
C_, DATE(LEFT(C2, 4), MID(C2, 6, 2), RIGHT(C2, 2)),
num_days, TODAY() - C_,
IFS(
D2 <> "New",
"",
num_days < 30,
"New",
(num_days > 30) * (num_days < 60),
"Move to In-Process",
num_days > 60,
"Past Due Move to In-Process"
)
)        Can you please explain how your equation here works?

Hi @BenjaminJ.Temple, please see whether the updated answer makes the steps clearer.
